# Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I am trying to include Jquery and Bootstrap 4 in Angular CLI project.

This is the first time I am trying to integrate these two.

So, I installed Jquery, PopperJs and  Bootstrap 4 and able to find these folders in Node module.

The issue is, when I refer these in the solution in Index.html page, styles are not working. If I comment out those and tried to add CDN Files as mentioned in this link

https://getbootstrap.com/

If I comment out node modules reference and put directly CDN reference it is working, another way is not.

Did I miss anything as part of Installation or references?

Comment: you may want to look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) it has question on how to import third party libs to angular with or without typings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the style files in .angular-cli.json

The file is located here:

- RootProjectFile
- e2e
- node_modules
- src
- **.angular-cli.json**

And then add it to the styles:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/..YourBootStrapStyle",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. What about the Jquery and Popper Js?

Comment: In some cases it is simply enough to import them in the `"scripts":[ ]`. also located in the .angular-cli.json